# Create PDF of the first page in an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have the following VBA Code to create a **PDF** out of **Sheet1** in the Excel file:

```
Sub Create_PDF()
    Sheet1.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Only First Page" & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

**Sheet1** consists of more than 1 page thus the code above currently creates a PDF file with all the pages in **Sheet1**. However, I want to achieve that *only the first page* is shown in the PDF.

What do I have to change in my code to exclude the other pages in Sheet1?

Comment: You can use a range function. so `sheet1.range("A1:I36").Export...` just change the range to select everything on your 1st page

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to specify your range of page 1. For example, if page 1 ranged from A1 to I 36 add this piece of code `range("A1:I36")`. See below:

```
Sub Create_PDF()
Sheet1.Range("A1:I36").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Only First Page" & ".pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

There is probably a better way but I can't think of it right now. Hopefully someone else will.